# Angular img source within ng-repeat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ROR application and I'm integrating a small angularJS on the client side (using HAML for the templates).
I have two issues I'm not sure how to address:

1. I'm placing my images under "app/assets/javascripts/images/" is it the right place to keep my images? (please keep in mind that I'm using assets pipeline)

Here's my code:

```
.box{ "ng-repeat" => "s in treatments.services", "ng-show" => "true"}
  .category-title
    {{ s.category }}
  %img{"src" => "/assets/images/icon_{{ s.category }}.png"}
```

2. I have 4 services, and everything looks visually good, the thing is that I'm getting a 404 (Not Found) JS error, looking at the 'network' tab in the developers tool (I'm using chrome) I can see all the expected Get requests foreach service's category I have and one EXTRA request (the false one that caused the js not found error) to http://localhost:3001/assets/images/**icon_**%7B%7B%20**category**%20%7D%7D**.png**
   Here's a valid request that I can also see going through:
   http://localhost:3001/assets/images/icon_xray.png
   Any idea why this extra get request happens?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular markup in a src attribute doesn't work, the markup will be used as it is in the source link. You should instead use `ng-src` :

```
.box{ "ng-repeat" => "s in treatments.services", "ng-show" => "true"}
  .category-title
    {{ s.category }}
  %img{"ng-src" => "/assets/images/icon_{{ s.category }}.png"}
```

More info here : [AngularJS: API: ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

About the images, it should normally be placed under 'app/assets/images', and then from the client side you access it with '/assets/img.png'.